# SolrException: maxNumThreadStates must be >= 1 but was: 0

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud, sunspot-solr

SolrException: maxNumThreadStates must be >= 1 but was: 0

**I get following response while trying to create core. Can anyone help on how to deal with *maxNumThreadStates*?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">500</int>
<int name="QTime">629</int>
</lst><lst name="error">
<str name="msg">maxNumThreadStates must be &gt;= 1 but was: 0</str>
<str name="trace">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: maxNumThreadStates must be &gt;= 1 but was: 0
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: maxNumThreadStates must be &gt;= 1 but was: 0
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThreadPool.&lt;init&gt;(DocumentsWriterPerThreadPool.java:142)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThreadPool.clone(DocumentsWriterPerThreadPool.java:360)
        at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexConfig.toIndexWriterConfig(SolrIndexConfig.java:261)
        at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.&lt;init&gt;(SolrIndexWriter.java:80)
        at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:66)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:550)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.&lt;init&gt;(SolrCore.java:806)
        ... 38 more
    </str><int name="code">500</int></lst><str name="params">name=profile.user&amp;action=CREATE</str>
    </response>
```

Comment: have you solved that one ? If not can you share your schema.xml + your solr exact version please?